# Get single data in Jersey Framework

Tags: java, jersey

How to get single data in jersery framework. I have done getall Data but cannot able to get single data. how to do it can someone help. My Resource Class:

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public Response getallLipid() {
    LipidDAO dao = new LipidDAO();
    List lipid = dao.getallLipid();
    String json = new Gson().toJson(lipid);
    return Response.ok().entity(json.toString()).build();
}
```

My DAO Class:

```
public List<Lipid> getallLipid(){
    Session session = SessionUtil.getSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("from Lipid");
    List<Lipid> lipids =  query.list();
    session.close();
    return lipids;
}

public List<Lipid> getLipid(){
    Session session = SessionUtil.getSession();

    Query query = session.createQuery("from Lipid");
    List<Lipid> lipids =  query.list();
    session.close();
    return lipids;
}
```

Here In getLipid()
I want to pass LipidId as a int.. How to Do it.. I tried many tutorials and all but cannot find the solution.. pls help to come out of this problem.

Comment: if you just want to send int the why send as json ,send it directly

Comment: How?? Can u explain me through code as well??

Answer (score 0):

Hi as per comment you can send int directly

Check below code here Integer is sent directly to client

```
@GET
@Path("checkValidity/{param}")
public Integer isUserValid(@PathParam("param") String id) throws NumberFormatException, InterruptedException {

    Integer id = getLipid()

    return id ;

}
```

You can change getLipid method and

```
public Integer getLipid(){
    Session session = SessionUtil.getSession();

    Query query = session.createQuery("from Lipid");
    List<Lipid> lipids =  query.list();
    session.close();
    return lipids.get(0).getLipid;
}
```

Comment: Sorry Bt in my code wat i need to do?? I need to change in DAO And Resources Class As well.. Wat will be the change

Comment: public List<Lipid> getLipid(int LipidId) {
        Session session = SessionUtil.getSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Lipid where LipidId = :LipidId");
      List<Lipid> lipids = query.list();
          return lipids;
    }

Comment: Above Code I have written for getsingle data..     Named parameter [LipidId] not set. This is error m getting